# Avoid requesting the same external script twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I request an external script by adding this to my HTML file:

```html
<script>
  $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
    $.getScript("https://example.com/script");
  });
</script>
```

Say the content of the script is as follows:

```js
doSomething = function() {
  // ...
};
```

My website is a Ruby on Rails app with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks), which caches the content of the requested script between page visits. My script tag does not know about this, so if I revisit the page it will request the script again. How do I avoid this? My current solution is to check if the scripts content is known:

```html
<script>
  $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
    if (!window.doSomething) {
      $.getScript("https://example.com/script");
    }
  });
</script>
```

But this depends on the content inside the script staying the same. So I would rather check if a script from the source `https://example.com/script` already exists? Or maybe some other approach. Any ideas?

Comment: jquery appends the script to the head so see if it exists

Comment: @Popnoodles I was hoping for a one liner, rather than these multistep answers.

Comment: @epascarello hm upon checking my head manually seems I can't find the script anywhere, though has clearly been loaded.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 so do as epascarello suggests

Answer (score 0):

Like epascarello commented, $.getScript appends to head so check that it's not in head before getting it.

```
if (!$('head script[src^="https://example.com/script"]').length){
    $.getScript("https://example.com/script");
}
```

Use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) because $.getScript appends a timestamp to avoid getting an already cached version, i.e. it requests a new URL each time.

If you're going to use it more than once:

```
function getScriptOnce(url){
    let selector = 'head script[src^="' + url + '"]'; 
    if (!$(selector).length){
        $.getScript(url);
    }
}

getScriptOnce("https://example.com/script");
```